# Is it recommended to include a preposition when listing several components of a sentence in parallel?

Tags: prepositions, parallelism

Consider the sample sentence below (quoted from a manual [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Summary.html)):

> When you evaluate a list, the Lisp interpreter looks **at the first symbol in the list** and then **at the function definition bound to that symbol**. Then the instructions in the function definition are carried out.

My question is: is it recommended to keep the duplicated "at" in the second bold text? 
Is it ALWAYS recommended to keep the preposition before such parallel structure?

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Repeated chunks like articles and prepositions can be deleted by [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+conjunction+reduction+preposition), but that is an optional rule, and prepositions may be repeated for clarity, as here.

Comment: Yes; no. Here it certainly simplifies. With 'Second crisis hits the bankers to the great and the good' it would be inappropriate to add a second 'to'. In 'I gave $200 to John and Sally', it can change the meaning deduced. In 'I asked for John and Sally', a second 'for' is optional.

Comment: @JohnLawler, THanks for the tips! Just wanted to confirm it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Thanks for the advice. It serves as a double confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Repeated chunks like articles and prepositions can be deleted by [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+conjunction+reduction+preposition), but that is an optional rule, and prepositions may be repeated for clarity, as here.

In your example, where each object is a sentence in itself, it certainly simplifies. With 'Second crisis hits the bankers to the great and the good' it would be inappropriate to add a second 'to'. In 'I gave $200 to John and Sally', it can change the meaning deduced. In 'I asked for John and Sally', a second 'for' is optional.

(Copying John's and Edwin's answers in the comments.)